# composer in a gulp build and deployment

Tags: gulp, composer-php

How do you get composer to install dependencies correctly whenusing a gulp build?

My build process set up that outputs to a set location, either `../sites/www/public_html` or `../sites/dev/public_html` dependent on if an environment argument is passed to a gulp task. These locations essentially mirror my remote host.

I'm wanting to automate composer installs, updates and optimisation to output the correct vendor files in either `../sites/www/vendor` or `../sites/dev/vendor` whenever the build is initially run or to just optimise based on any watched php files being changed.

My build folder has the following structure:

```
source/
bower.json
composer.json
composer.lock
gulpfile.json
package.json
```

My example composer.json has the following:

```
{
    "name": "mycomposer/mycomposer",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4" : {
            "mycomposer\\": "public_html/app/mycomposer"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "rollbar/rollbar": "^1.3",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4.0"
    }
}
```

I have tried a gulp-compose and task to install the composer libraries and to run `dumpautoload` for local first party libraries

```
gulp.task('composer', function() {

  var dest = argv.live ? 'www' : 'devsite',
     env = '../sites/' + dest + '/public_html';

  $.composer('config vendor-dir ' + env.replace('public_html', 'vendor') );

  $.composer({
    "no-ansi": true,
    "no-dev": true,
     "no-interaction":  true,
     "no-progress":  true,
     "no-scripts":  true,
     "optimize-autoloader": true
  });

  $.composer('dumpautoload ', {
    optimize: true
  });
});
```

When the task is complete I'm finding is that the `$baseDir` variable references the build directory

**Expected**

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);
```

**Output**

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname(dirname(dirname($vendorDir))).'/mybuild';
```

Is this something I can achieve, or should I really be running composer separately from my build process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.
I use [gulp-composer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-composer) package.

### gulpfile.js

```
const composer = require('gulp-composer');

gulp.task('composer-deployed', async function() {
     
    let opts = {
        "working-dir": 'my-path-to-composer.json',
        "self-install": true, // false for my case
        optimize: true,
        "classmap-authoritative": true
    };
    composer("dumpautoload", opts);
});
```

In my case, I use composer installed globaly but you can choose the bin path with `bin: 'path-to-composer.phar'` in `opts{}`.